# count on you to show up/showing up today

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

1. I just wanted to make sure I can count on you to show up today.
2. I just wanted to make sure I can count on you showing up today.

Are these versions equally correct and natural? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Both are certainly natural for English speakers. However, there are two grammar issues that you should be aware of.

1. Because "wanted" is in the past tense, I think that most people would prefer the modal verb ("can") to be in the preterite form ("could"). However, many people would be fine with "can".
2. Some people would object to the second sentence because of "you showing". I won't give an explanation that's already been given on ELL; you can read about the issue here:

[When to use an object pronoun or a possessive adjective before a gerund](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19038/when-to-use-an-object-pronoun-or-a-possessive-adjective-before-a-gerund)

and here:

[Possessive gerund](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/121990/possessive-gerund)